# Accessing the response from one GET request within another

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm working with Vue to interact with an external API on a Drupal website, but in order to do so dynamically per Drupal user, I need to get a token from Drupal first. To do so, I'm trying to do two `GET` requests. The first gets me a bearer token out of Drupal, and the second uses it to authenticate the third-party API request.

Below is what I'm trying – I'm able to get the token successfully in the first request's response, but not when I try to use it in the header of my second request. If I try hardcoding the token that I see in the console log, it does work, so I know none of that is the issue. It's just that `this.jwt['data']['token']` in the second request's headers seems to not pull back the token.

What do I need to adjust in order to access the token from the first response as part of the headers of my second request?

```js
created() {
    axios
    .get('/jwt/token')
    .then(response => {
        this.jwt = response
        console.log(this.jwt['data']['token']) // this does show what I want to access later
    })
},
mounted() {
    axios
    .get('/comment/doc/' + this.id, {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + this.jwt['data']['token'] } // ...but this doesn't work
    })
    .then(response => {
        this.comments = response
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the response to the token request has not finished by the time the component mounts, at which point `this.jwt` is not yet assigned.

I would move the token request into the `mounted` hook, fetching comments only when the token request succeeds:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('/jwt/token')
      .then(tokenResp => {
        this.jwt = tokenResp

        axios
          .get('/comment/doc/' + this.id, {
            headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.jwt['data']['token'] }
          })
          .then(commentsResp => {
            this.comments = commentsResp
          })
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you; this worked. As a somewhat related follow-up, would the token request have finished in time for a method to use `this.jwt`? I'm noticing some issues with them after making this adjustment, but it may be unrelated, in which case I'll add a new question if I need to.

Comment: That depends. Given that nothing waits for the token request to complete (i.e., it's not `await`ed and there is no `then` callback), anything that relies on the token is **not** guaranteed to have a value for `this.jwt`. It would only work if the token request is processed fast enough before it is used, but the request itself is dependent on network conditions, which could vary. Your best bet is to `await` the request before using `this.jwt`.